# Use in spring boot application into in other

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I want to integrate my spring boot project into in another.
For this I export the `.jar` and I put it in the libraries of the other project which is also spring boot.
 My .jar is :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B96L3Vd9zNeoQzhhcmFjT05vRWc/view?usp=sharing

And my main in the other project is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class UpsysmarocApplicationTestlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(UpsysmarocApplicationTestlogApplication.class, args);
        TraceabilityLogService traceabilityLogService = context.getBean(TraceabilityLogService.class);

        List<Map<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("element", "Nom");
        item.put("oldValue", "Mkharbach2");
        item.put("newValue", "Mounji2");
        items.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("element", "Prenom");
        item.put("oldValue", "Ayoub2");
        item.put("newValue", "Said2");
        items.add(item);

        List<Map<String, String>> connections = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> connection = new HashMap<>();
        connection.put("className", "User");
        connection.put("originId", "3");
        connections.add(connection);

        TraceabilityLog traceabilityLog = traceabilityLogService.save("Eladlani2", "CREATION", items, connections);
        System.out.println("RETURN => " + traceabilityLog.getId());
    }

}
```

But i want another way that does not ask to instantiate the context but just to use the functionality fornie part our module
So I always wait for the best method that works well and thanks in advance.

Thank you.

Comment: What problem? Where is your code?

Comment: I modified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I puted the project as maven dependency.